# print multiple words in specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, text

I have a file **word.txt**

$ cat word.txt

```
cat
dog
rat
bird
```

I have a **URL** like this

```
https://example.com/?word=
```

I want to generate a URL list like this

```
https://example.com/?word=cat

https://example.com/?word=cat,dog

https://example.com/?word=cat,dog,rat

https://example.com/?word=cat,dog,rat,bird
```

I have **177** words so how can I automate this process with **Bash** or any other easy programming

Comment: _or any other easy programming_ : I think this can be done with virtually any programming language. Just choose the one you are most familiar with.

Comment: I would suggest implementing a solution for this in python, as it is very easy to get started with and has a great file handling. I would not go for bash, as that is more for OS-related operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the input line by line, add the line to the URL. Don't include the comma for the first line.

```
#! /bin/bash
url='https://example.com/?word='
while read -r line ; do
    url+=$comma$line
    comma=,
    echo "$url"
done < word.txt
```

Comment: "Thanks" on StackOverflow = upvote / accept :)

Comment: Done brother. 
Thanks again for your awesome support

Answer (score 1):

This task can be accomplished with a single GNU `sed` command:

```
sed -n 's|^|https://example.com/?word=|; :a; p; N; s/\n/,/; ba' word.txt
```

That should be more efficient than the plain `bash`.

---

**Explanation:**

- **-n**   With this option, `sed` only produces output when explicitly told to via the `p` command.
- **s|^|https://example.com/?word=|**   Replaces the beginning of the line with the `https://example.com/?word=`. This command effectively prepends that string to the pattern space.
- **:a**   Label *a* for branch command (`b`). Used when looping through the lines.
- **p**   Prints the pattern space.
- **N**   Adds a *newline* to the pattern space, then appends the next line of input to the pattern space.
- **s/\n/,/**   Replaces the *newline* with the comma (`,`).
- **ba**   Jumps to the label *a*. This effectively creates a loop for all input lines except the first line.

Comment: Very nice, could you please explain what magic is happening here?

Comment: @Ivan I've added an explanation and modified the `sed` command slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
url='https://example.com/?word='
while read word; do
    words+=($word)   list="${words[@]}"
    printf '%s%s\n' "$url" ${list// /,}
done < word.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you want to do it in python

```
words=["a","b","c"]
joinedWords = ",".join(words)
url="https://example.com/?word="
print(url,joinedWords)
reqUrl = url+joinedWords
print(reqUrl)
```